# GeospatialPDF javascript access

Tags: gdal, javascript, geospatial-pdf

Using javascript in GeospatialPDF, is it possible to zoom in to an extent, say when the document is opened the first time ?

To what extent can I use javascript to access the geospatial data? pan, zoom, turn-on/off layer ?

From GDAL Geospatial format page:
Create of PDF with some JavaScript :

```
gdal_translate -of PDF my.tif my.pdf -co JAVASCRIPT_FILE=script.js
```

where script.js is :

```
button = app.alert({cMsg: 'This file was generated by GDAL. Do you want to visit its    
website ?', cTitle: 'Question', nIcon:2, nType:2});
if (button == 4) app.launchURL('http://gdal.org/');
```